# Determining the status of Transaction after disposal

Tags: c#, multithreading, transactions, transactionscope

I am trying to determine if the transaction has been completed or not, and depending on the results, I want to do other stuff in another thread.

Consider the below TransactionScope:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Do stuff

    Scope.Complete();
}
```

Now, in another class, in a separate thread, I am going through a list of objects that have similar transactions:

```
private static void ProcessActions()
{
    while(true)
    {
        action = pendingActions[0];
        if (action.CurrentTransaction == null || 
            action.CurrentTransaction.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Committed)
        {
            // Proceed to do things!!
            remove = true;
        }
        else if (action.CurrentTransaction.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Aborted)
        {
            // Transaction has aborted. Remove this action from the list
            remove = true;
        }

        if (remove)
        {
            lock (pendingActions)
            {
                pendingActions.Remove(action);
                eventCount = pendingActions.Count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I set the CurrentTransaction for an action when I am creating a new action in the constructor:

```
public Action()
{
    CurrentTransaction = System.Transactions.Transaction.Current;
}
```

The problem is that by the time the other thread is processing the actions, action.CurrentTransaction is disposed, throwing System.ObjectDisposedException.

How can I keep track of the status for each transaction in an Action before it gets disposed?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @VMAtm I simply wanted to check to see if the Transaction for each action is still processing, aborted, or commited before proceeding to do other things. I think I have found a solution. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution by utilizing [Transaction.TransactionCompleted Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioncompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).

I used the below code to assign a delegate to the TransactionCompleted event:

```
System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += new TransactionCompletedEventHandler(Mother.Current_TransactionCompleted);
```

In that method, I was able to iterate through my actions and determine which one has the corresponding origin Transaction. Like this:

```
public static void Current_TransactionCompleted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
{
    var originatingTransaction = sender as System.Transactions.Transaction;

    lock (pendingActions)
    {
        for (int i = pendingActions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var action = pendingActions[i];

            if (originatingTransaction.Equals(action.CurrentTransaction))
            {
                var transactionStatus = e.Transaction.TransactionInformation.Status;
                if (transactionStatus == TransactionStatus.Committed)
                {
                    // Later in the code, I will do stuff if CurrentTransaction is null
                    action.CurrentTransaction = null;
                }
                else if (transactionStatus == TransactionStatus.Aborted)
                {
                    // if It's aborted, I will remove this action
                    pendingActions.RemoveAt(i);
                }
                // I will skip processing any actions that still have a Transaction with the status of "Processing"
            }
        }
    }
}
```